# Are these TWO pieces of code doing the same thing?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am working on an Android Application which saves data to an SQLite database. I've removed the first piece of code as I believe the second piece of code is already doing the same thing. I have run a few tests and everything still seems to be working perfectly. Is there any further purpose for the first piece of code?

First piece of code....

```
Cursor res = myDb.getRoutineForCurrentDay(currentDay);

                if (res.getCount() == 0) {

                } else {
                    //data found, show on screen
                        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                        while (res.moveToNext()) {
                            buffer.append("Id : " + res.getString(0) + "\n");
                            buffer.append("Day : " + res.getString(1) + "\n");
                            buffer.append("Act : " + res.getString(2) + "\n");
                            buffer.append("Slot : " + res.getString(3) + "\n");
                        }
                }

                ImageID = 0;

                break;
```

Second piece of code....

```
private void getRoutine() {
    Cursor res = myDb.getRoutineForCurrentDay(currentDay);

    if (res.getCount() == 0) {

    } else {
        //data found, show on screen
        while (res.moveToNext()) {
            int ActID = res.getInt(2);
            int SlotID = res.getInt(3);
            ImageView slot = (ImageView) findViewById(SlotID);
            slot.setImageResource(ActID);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the second piece of code sets up an Imageview and populates it, while the first piece of code only processes the info as text.

My guess would be someone wrote the first piece of code just to check whether or not the local DB contains the correct values.

The second snippet should be all you need.